# How to enable webmaster tools in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

Whenever I try to enable webmaster tools from within my Google analytics account, the following happens:

**I click on SEO section from within analytics:**

---

[image]

---

.

**A screen appears notifying me I need to enable webmaster tools:**
.

---

[image]

---

**I click on "setup webmaster tools" button**

---

[image]

---

**Im presented with an options screen - I click save and am given a green "success" indicator**

---

However when I go back in to analytics and click seo again, I am presented with the exact same screen again. (this report requires webmaster tools to be enabled). As if nothing had changed.
.

can anyone tell me how to enable webmaster tools successfully? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click "Edit" and then add a site to Webmaster tools. The Save button is just to save the Property settings.